# react hooks changing state seems no change when calling from function to another

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Here's what I have done so far:

Every time when changing checbox value either true/false it seems like the value from `fetchAnswers` function twisted from `checkBoxAction` function. Here's the original demo code in snack [demo code](https://snack.expo.dev/@vicrn101/react-hooks-state-issue). Notice that on console log that value from `fetchAnswers` oppose from the value coming from `checkBoxAction`

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, CheckBox } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';


import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {
 const [showNew, setShowNew] = useState(true);

 const checkBoxAction =  async (status, checkBoxStatus) => {
    if(status === 'new') {
        console.log('checkBoxAction: ', checkBoxStatus)
        setShowNew(checkBoxStatus)
    }

    fetchAnswers()
 }

const fetchAnswers = async () => {
    console.log('fetchAnswers: ', showNew)
}

return (
 <View style={styles.container}>
    <CheckBox
        value={showNew}
        onChange={()=> checkBoxAction('new',(showNew?false:true))}
    />
  <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
    
  </Text>
</View>


 );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  padding: 8,
},
paragraph: {
margin: 24,
fontSize: 18,
fontWeight: 'bold',
textAlign: 'center',


},



});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setShowNew is setting the value after the whole function is done. That is why you see old values when you console log them.
Either console.log checkBoxStatus since it is the newest value, or use an useEffect.

```
useEffect(()=> {
    console.log(showNew)
}, [showNew]) //Only run when showNew changes
```